# How to get spring boot rest api to send mixed content in response ( structured content plus attachment )

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am new to handling attachments in REST apis. I have a requirement to produce certain metadata about files , which would be a regular json response, plus multiple file contents as attachments. Is this kind of mixed content possible using spring boot ? Or is this even a valid use case ? Normally the apis I have seen as examples have only file content written to the response stream.

If case this can be achieved, what should be the content-type header ?

I tried experimenting for some time with this kind of controller --

@GetMapping("/configmetadata")
public ResponseEntity getConfigs(@RequestParam(name = "id") String identifier) {

...
}

In this structure, I can send back the structured portion , which is ConfigResponse but I am not sure how to send the file content as attachment.

I have also tried including ByteArrayResource or MultipartFile as part of "ConfigResponse" object , but they fail with serialization issues.

Some guidance over here would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider sending multiple files via a REST response a bad practice.
Doing so would mean that you would need to serialize your file contents into valid JSON or XML. How would that look like?

Instead I would recommend that you add download-links to the respective Response Object, which would serialize and perform very well as part of your Response Body. The client could then resolve the links to download the files via a regular download protocol instead of re-building the files from JSON-serialized byte code.

Comment: Yes obviously  I wouldn't like the file content to be serialized and deserialized as regular json object that's why still want to treat them as attachment. I was more arriving from the fact that while sending a file as part  of request, it is feasible to send a structured content plus a multi-part data , which probably saves a few round trips for the clients.

Comment: I guess for now I'll accept your answer, unless I hear any pressing need to reduce round trips by client code.